# Unnamed pipes in C, chaning stdin,stdout in fork()

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I'm trying to write a program that will implement command:

```
ls -al | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | grep X > testing
```

Basically I want to learn how to use piping twice in C. There is a lot of post where we're using only one '|'. I made some attempts based on examples with only one '|' but sadly it doesn't work. There is a code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MAX 512
int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int pdesk[2];
    int pipedesk[2];
    if(pipe(pipedesk)==-1 || pipe(pdesk)==-1){
        perror("Pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch(fork()){
        case -1 :
                perror("Creating process");
                exit(1);
        case 0:
                dup2(pdesk[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(pdesk[1]);
                execlp("ls","ls","-al",NULL);
                perror("ls");
                exit(1);
        default: {
                if(fork()==0){
                    if(fork()==0){
                        dup2(pdesk[0],STDIN_FILENO);
                        close(pdesk[0]);
                        dup2(pipedesk[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
                        close(pipedesk[1]);
                        execlp("tr","tr","a-z","A-Z",NULL);
                        perror("tr");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    dup2(pipedesk[0],STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(pipedesk[0]);
                    int desk=open("testing",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0640);
                    if(desk==-1){
                        perror("opening file");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    dup2(desk,STDOUT_FILENO);
                    if(close(desk)==-1){
                        perror("closing file");
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    execlp("grep","grep","X",NULL);
                    perror("grep");
                    exit(1);
                }
//              wait(NULL);

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work???

Comment: Please avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Use predefined macros like `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` instead. Also, you are missing a crucial header file inclusion.

Comment: As for your problem, you need *two* pipes. You can't reuse an existing pipe.

Comment: So I edided my first post. Tried using two pipes, same outcome :/ . I thought that maybe me using dup2 with file is bad, but with our without it outcome doesn't change.

Comment: Try doing it in smaller steps. First make sure the process with the `ls` command works as expected, without pipes. Then add a pipe for the output of the `ls` command, piping to the *parent* process. Then add another child process which just reads the pipe and outputs it. Then the second child process executes the `tr` command. And so on. Baby steps. Verifying that each step works as expected before continuing to the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that signal handling is relevant.  What is relevant is making sure that pipes are closed properly.  Processes won't get EOF on the reading end of a pipe if there's a process with the writing end open.  That includes the current process; if a process has both the reading and writing ends of a pipe open, it will never get EOF on the reading end of the pipe because there is a process that could, in theory, write to it.  Such a process therefore hangs permanently in a `read()` on the pipe.

This version of your code works fine for me:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pdesk[2];
    int pipedesk[2];
    int pid;

    if (pipe(pipedesk) == -1 || pipe(pdesk) == -1)
    {
        perror("Pipe");
        exit(1);
    }
    //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: controller\n", (int)getpid());

    switch (pid = fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("Creating process");
        exit(1);
    case 0:
        //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: will be 'ls'\n", (int)getpid());
        dup2(pdesk[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pdesk[0]);        // JL
        close(pdesk[1]);
        close(pipedesk[0]);     // JL
        close(pipedesk[1]);     // JL
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-al", (char *)NULL);
        perror("ls");
        exit(1);
    default:
        //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: ls process PID = %d\n", (int)getpid(), pid);
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: about to fork 'tr'\n", (int)getpid());
            if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
            {
                //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: will be 'tr'\n", (int)getpid());
                dup2(pdesk[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                close(pdesk[0]);
                close(pdesk[1]);        // JL
                dup2(pipedesk[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(pipedesk[0]);     // JL
                close(pipedesk[1]);
                execlp("tr", "tr", "a-z", "A-Z", (char *)NULL);
                perror("tr");
                exit(1);
            }
            //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: about to exec 'grep'\n", (int)getpid());
            dup2(pipedesk[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pdesk[0]);        // JL
            close(pdesk[1]);        // JL
            close(pipedesk[0]);
            close(pipedesk[1]);     // JL
            int desk = open("testing", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
            if (desk == -1)
            {
                perror("opening file");
                exit(1);
            }
            dup2(desk, STDOUT_FILENO);
            if (close(desk) == -1)
            {
                perror("closing file");
                exit(1);
            }
            execlp("grep", "grep", "X", (char *)NULL);
            perror("grep");
            exit(1);
        }

        //fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: closing pipes\n", (int)getpid());
        close(pdesk[0]);        // JL
        close(pdesk[1]);        // JL
        close(pipedesk[0]);     // JL
        close(pipedesk[1]);     // JL

        break;
    }

    int status;
    int corpse;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "PID %d: child %d died 0x%.4X\n", (int)getpid(), corpse, status);

    return 0;
}
```

Note all the lines marked `// JL` which are close operations.  While it is probably true that you can get away without a few of them (the ones for the first child, for example, are probably 'optional'), you should as a matter of routine close all the pipes that you are not using.  Note, in particular, the closes for the original parent process (the last four) — those are important.

Not closing enough pipe descriptors is one of the most common mistakes when working with multiple pipes.  In general, if you use `dup2()` (or `dup()`) to duplicate a pipe descriptor to standard input or output, you should close *both* ends of the original pipe.  And if your process is not using the pipe descriptors at all, you should close them.

Sample output from program:

```
$ ./pp61
PID 35665: child 35666 died 0x0000
PID 35665: child 35667 died 0x0000
$
```

Sample contents of `testing` file:

```
DRWXR-XR-X   44 JLEFFLER  STAFF   1496 NOV 23 17:28 .
DRWXR-XR-X  137 JLEFFLER  STAFF   4658 NOV 23 17:28 ..
DRWXR-XR-X   18 JLEFFLER  STAFF    612 OCT 23 20:00 .GIT
DR-XR-XR-X    4 JLEFFLER  STAFF    136 AUG 14 23:27 SAFE
DRWXR-XR-X   35 JLEFFLER  STAFF   1190 NOV 23 09:19 UNTRACKED
-RW-R--R--    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF     81 NOV 20 20:53 ANIMALS.TXT
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 SEP 12 00:03 DOC
DRWXR-XR-X    8 JLEFFLER  STAFF    272 NOV 10 20:58 ETC
DRWXR-XR-X   17 JLEFFLER  STAFF    578 JUL 15 19:06 INC
-RW-R--R--    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   1217 NOV 21 21:26 IX37.SQL
DRWXR-XR-X    5 JLEFFLER  STAFF    170 JUL  9 23:47 LIB
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   9052 NOV 19 13:01 LL73
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV  6 15:40 LL73.DSYM
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   8896 NOV  6 10:38 LL83
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV  6 10:10 LL83.DSYM
-RW-R--R--    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF    108 NOV 20 20:53 NEWANIMAL.TXT
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   9124 NOV 20 20:38 PD43
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV 20 20:38 PD43.DSYM
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   9148 NOV 23 17:28 PP61
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV 23 14:11 PP61.DSYM
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   9016 NOV 23 11:07 RS19
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV 23 10:03 RS19.DSYM
DRWXR-XR-X  146 JLEFFLER  STAFF   4964 OCT  9 17:06 SRC
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   8760 NOV 23 13:12 STP83
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV 23 13:04 STP83.DSYM
DRWXR-XR-X    6 JLEFFLER  STAFF    204 NOV  6 21:52 TMP
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF   8808 NOV 23 10:38 TR37
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV 23 10:38 TR37.DSYM
-RWXR-XR-X    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF  26772 NOV 21 20:18 XY73
DRWXR-XR-X    3 JLEFFLER  STAFF    102 NOV 21 20:18 XY73.DSYM
-RW-R--R--    1 JLEFFLER  STAFF    467 NOV 21 20:18 XY73.L
```

Answer (score 2):

When the other end of the pipe dies, your process receives a SIGPIPE which default to kill your process.

So you should at least ignore it !

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

In order to be clean, you should close all pipe ends you won't use in the current process.

For example :

```
case 0:
    close(pdesk[0]);
    close(pipedesk[0]);
    close(pipedesk[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you )for answer. So after adding signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN) my program will ingore SIGPIPE signa,right? I added <signal.h>, added this command at the beginning of main(), but sadly nothing changes... Would u mind giving me some more hints how to make my programm work ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation which is easy to understand.

One end of a pipe becomes closed when every process did close the other end of the pipe. So this is very important to close every pipes which are useless for the current process.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void closeAll(const int * fd_to_close){
    int i = 0;
    while(1){
        int fd = fd_to_close[i];
        if(fd == -1){
            break;
        }
        close(fd);
        i++;
    }
}

pid_t forkExec(int my_stdin, int my_stdout, int my_stderr, char *const argv[], const int* fd_to_close){
    pid_t child = fork();

    if(child != 0){
        return child;
    }

    if(my_stdin != STDIN_FILENO){
        dup2(my_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
    }
    if(my_stdout != STDOUT_FILENO){
        dup2(my_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
    if(my_stderr != STDERR_FILENO){
        dup2(my_stderr, STDERR_FILENO);
    }

    closeAll(fd_to_close);

    execvp(argv[0], argv);

    perror("Executing ");

    exit(1);
}

void waitFor(pid_t child){
    int status;
    pid_t w = waitpid(child, &status, 0);
    if(w == -1){
        perror("child ");
    } else {
        printf("Exit status of child %d was %d, killed by signal %d %s\n", (int) child, WEXITSTATUS(status), WTERMSIG(status), WCOREDUMP(status) ? "with coredump" : "");
    }
}

void main(int argc, char**argv){
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];
    int fd_to_close[10];

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    if(pipe(pipe1)==-1 || pipe(pipe2)==-1){
        perror("Pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    fd_to_close[0] = pipe1[0];
    fd_to_close[1] = pipe1[1];
    fd_to_close[2] = pipe2[0];
    fd_to_close[3] = pipe2[1];
    fd_to_close[4] = -1;

    char* cmd1[] = {"ls", "-al", NULL};
    char* cmd2[] = {"tr", "a-z", "A-Z", NULL};
    char* cmd3[] = {"grep", "X", NULL};

    pid_t child1 = forkExec(STDIN_FILENO, pipe1[1],      STDERR_FILENO, cmd1, fd_to_close);
    pid_t child2 = forkExec(pipe1[0],     pipe2[1],      STDERR_FILENO, cmd2, fd_to_close);
    pid_t child3 = forkExec(pipe2[0],     STDOUT_FILENO, STDERR_FILENO, cmd3, fd_to_close);

    // Very important :
    closeAll(fd_to_close);

    printf("pid of %s is %d\n", cmd1[0], (int)child1);
    printf("pid of %s is %d\n", cmd2[0], (int)child2);
    printf("pid of %s is %d\n", cmd3[0], (int)child3);

    waitFor(child1);
    waitFor(child2);
    waitFor(child3);
}
```